How to resume DB sync for Preview Testnet
I am using a remote Linux V-Server with 2-VCores, 120GB storage and 4GB RAM where I want  to run a Preview Testnet in my remote machine.
I have access to this machine using ssh
While running the preview testnet, a db folder and a node.socket will be created
cardano-node run +RTS -N2 --disable-delayed-os-memory-return -I0.3 -Iw600 -A16m -F1.5 -H2500M -T -S -RTS \
    --topology topology.json \
    --database-path db \
    --socket-path node.socket \
    --port 3001 \
    --config config.json

After few hours of download, I get Error in my terminal
Read from remote host IP_ADDRESS: Connection reset by peer 
Connection to IP_ADDRESS closed. 
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

This probably related to my SSH configuration. But when I tried to resume dowload using same command of cardano-node run
[cardano.#ekgview.realizeFrom:Error:5] [2024-11-04 05:52:55.98 UTC] EKGView backend disabled due to initialisation error: EKGServerStartupError "Network.Socket.bind: resource busy (Address already in use)"
[cardano.#ekgview.realizeFrom:Error:5] [2024-11-04 05:52:55.98 UTC] EKGView backend disabled due to initialisation error: EKGUnknownStartupError "capacity has to be greater than 0\nCallStack (from HasCallStack):\n  error, called at libraries/stm/Control/Concurrent/STM/TBQueue.hs:87:16 in stm-2.5.2.1-73cd:Control.Concurrent.STM.TBQueue"

cardano-node: capacity has to be greater than 0
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/stm/Control/Concurrent/STM/TBQueue.hs:87:16 in stm-2.5.2.1-73cd:Control.Concurrent.STM.TBQueue 48103912     30688    222824  0.000  0.001    0.117    0.155    1   56  (Gen:  1)
     1896                      0.000  0.000

      77,482,216 bytes allocated in the heap
         609,976 bytes copied during GC
         222,824 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          63,896 bytes maximum slop
            2517 MiB total memory in use (0 MiB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         1 colls,     1 par    0.035s   0.036s     0.0358s    0.0358s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.001s     0.0005s    0.0005s

  Parallel GC work balance: 3.57% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 8 (1 bound, 7 peak workers (7 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.080s  (  0.116s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.035s  (  0.036s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.004s  (  0.004s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.121s  (  0.159s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    971,074,865 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  66.1% of total user, 73.2% of total elapsed

How could resume download using the existing DB

I found a tip https://forum.cardano.org/t/updated-a-relay-to-1-23-0-getting-ekgview-error-any-workaround-or-is-this-a-bug/42664/9 that have solved this error by simply cheking if there is a cardano process still runing and then kill it
